# Unexpected behaviour when trying to access multiple columns

Tags: r, data.table

I'm having some trouble accessing variables in `j` on non-equi merges.

```
library(data.table)

DT = data.table(x=rep(c("b","a","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9, date = seq(as.Date("2019-03-15"), by ="days", length.out = 9))
DTI <- data.table(date = as.Date(c("2019-03-16", "2019-03-21")), size = 55, len = c(3, 4), len2 = c(5, 5))


len_var <- "i.len"


DT[DTI, {
  ct <- len;
  mm <- len2
  print(paste0("ct :", ct))
  print(paste0 ("mm: ", mm))
  i_min <- min(which(y > ct));
  i_min
},
on = .(date > date),
by = .EACHI, allow.cartesian = TRUE, verbose = FALSE]

# [1] "ct :3"
# [1] "mm: 5"
# [1] "ct :4"
# [1] "mm: 5"
# date V1
# 1: 2019-03-16  1
# 2: 2019-03-21  2


# works
DT[DTI, {
  ct <- get(len_var);
  mm <- get("len2") # this variable causes issue in the following examples
  print(paste0("ct :", ct))
  print(paste0 ("mm: ", mm))
  i_min <- min(which(y > ct));
  i_min
},
on = .(date > date),
by = .EACHI, allow.cartesian = TRUE, verbose = FALSE]

# [1] "ct :3"
# [1] "mm: 5"
# [1] "ct :4"
# [1] "mm: 5"
# date V1
# 1: 2019-03-16  1
# 2: 2019-03-21  2

#error ???
DT[DTI, {
  ct <- len;
  mm <- get("len2")
  print(paste0("ct :", ct))
  print(paste0 ("mm: ", mm))
  i_min <- min(which(y > ct));
  i_min
},
on = .(date > date),
by = .EACHI, allow.cartesian = TRUE, verbose = FALSE]

# Error in validate(cols, x) : 
#   cols value [len] not present (or out of range) in x
```

The last expression doesn't work. Why? it would work if I change `mm <- get("len2")` to  `mm <- len2`, but I want to dynamically pass in the column for some variables.  i.e. this works:

```
DT[DTI, {
  ct <- len;
  mm <- len2
  print(paste0("ct :", ct))
  print(paste0 ("mm: ", mm))
  i_min <- min(which(y > ct));
  i_min
},
on = .(date > date),
by = .EACHI, allow.cartesian = TRUE, verbose = FALSE]

1] "ct :3"
[1] "mm: 5"
[1] "ct :4"
[1] "mm: 5"
         date V1
1: 2019-03-16  1
2: 2019-03-21  2
```

What's going on? Am I missing something?  Is this expected behaviour in data.table? i.e. the way you access variables (columns) from the `i` data table in the `x[i, ]` merge need to be done in the same way (hard code the variable names, or use `get()` consistently for accessing each variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert it to a symbol (`as.name` or `as.symbol`) and it should work

```
DT[DTI, {
    ct <- len;
     mm <- as.name("len2")
     print(paste0("ct :", ct))
     print(paste0 ("mm: ", mm))
     i_min <- min(which(y > ct));
     i_min
    },
    on = .(date > date),
      by = .EACHI, allow.cartesian = TRUE, verbose = FALSE]
```

Comment: that prints `mm: len2`

Comment: @ChilliProject  But, check your output.  Your print statement is one of the 'mm' and not on the value of it

Comment: +1 Ok. can you explain why the error above is occurring though?  feels like something about the data.table environments that I don't quite grasp

Comment: @ChilliProject  Is the `print` statement important or the actual join?

Comment: @ChilliProject `get` looks for objects in an environment.  You may need to specify the correct env and it can get messy

Comment: mainly the join.  is as.name or as.symbol more efficient that using `get`?

Comment: @ChilliProject  I think both should be almost same.  But, with `get`,  it is better to specify the `envir`